# Проверить цифровую подпись exe в линуксе

Tags: linux, windows, exe, signature

Я хочу в линуксе, проверить, содержит ли виндовый exe-файл валидную цифровую подпись и достать из неё несколько полей, а именно издателя и дату подписания.

Как это сделать? Желательно через командную строку.

PS: [Этот вопрос на английском](https://askubuntu.com/q/1198401/511165).

Comment: первая ссылка в гугле по запросу "linux check exe file sign": https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/269906/how-can-i-extract-signatures-data-from-a-windows-exe-file-under-linux-using-cl

Comment: @Fat-Zer, прикольно, я как-то не так искал.

Comment: @Fat-Zer, кажется не проверяет отозванные и просроченные.

Comment: гм... внутри всё на Си с openssl'ем... проверку просрочки вроде как добавить будет не сложно, а вот с отзывом — не уверен, как это должно работать...